# How to add meta tag on head and click through tags using edge animate

Tags: jquery, html

So, I am obviously a noob here. Some designers have built some web banners for me using Edge Animate and now the media agency is asking us to add click through tags as per the below:

**Click-through Tag Requirements**

The HTML file must include a meta tag indicating which element in the ad triggers the clickthrough.

- Specify the click-through element with a ‘click.through’ meta tag. Insert your HTML file’s clickable element ID where it says myClickableElementId:
- Format:

  ```html
  <meta name=”click.through” content=”myClickableElementId” >
  ```
- Ensure the HTML file contains an element with the specified ID. The ID should be set on the `<img>` itself and not on any wrapping `<div>`s.

  ```html
  <div id=”cta”>
    <div id=”cta_copy”><img id=”myClickableElementId” src=”button.png” ></div>
  </div>
  ```

Can anyone provide some instruction here on how I can do this within Adobe Edge Animate? I can add header text to the original file, but I don't know how to add the right code in the injected script for the banner that will link to the meta tag.

Comment: NB: [Edge Animate has been discontinued](https://helpx.adobe.com/edge-animate/edge-development-faq.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use Edge Animate for this.

You use Edge Animate to create the animation. Then you use your regular HTML editor to create an HTML document and put the animation code in it. You also use your regular editor to create the meta element.